# TabLayout with ViewPager on new tab selection previous tab text disappers

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm using TabLayout with ViewPager for showing data as requested.
In tab layout, my requirement is, I've to set a different font for the selected item and a different one for others. I write the following code for this.

But I'm facing one issue. Suppose I've 4 items "One", "Two", "Three" and "Four". Initially "One" is default selected with Bold font, and others are with normal font. But when I click "Two" tab "One" tab disappears. When I click on "Three" tab "Two" tab disappears and "One" tab visible with normal font.

```
private void setupViewPager(CustomViewPager viewPager, TabLayout tabLayout, ArrayList<TipsInfo> mListTips) {
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        for (int i = 0; i < mListTips.size(); i++) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mListTips.get(i).getValue()))
                adapter.addFragment(TipsDetailFragment.newInstance(mListTips.get(i).getValue()), mListTips.get(i).getLabel());
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        View tabContent = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_tips_tablayout_selected, null);
        TextView selected = tabContent.findViewById(R.id.tv_tips_selected_tab);
        View tabContent1 = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_tips_tablayout_unselected, null);
        TextView unselected = tabContent1.findViewById(R.id.tv_tips_unselected_tab);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(
                new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        selected.setText(tab.getText());
                        tab.setCustomView(selected);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                        unselected.setText(tab.getText());
                        tab.setCustomView(unselected);
//
//                        for(int i=0; i<tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++){
//                            if(i != tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()){
//                                unselected.setText(tabLayout.getTabAt(i).getText());
//                                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(unselected);
//                            }
//                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        onTabSelected(tab);
                    }
                }
        );

    }
```

My `ViewPaerAdapter` is extended with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and its object is created with `getChildFragmentManager`. My XML code look's like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tl_tips"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:elevation="@dimen/v1dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:gravity="start"
            app:tabMinWidth="@dimen/v100dp"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorBannerNewDotSelected"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/v3dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorBlackDark"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorServiceCount"
            />
```

`item_tips_tablayout_selected` and `item_tips_tablayout_unselected` contains only TextView with different fonts applied to it.

Screenshots:

1. Initial

[image]

2. When clicked on "Benefits", the font applied to it but "How to use" disappeared.

[image]

3. When clicked on "Product Use", the font applied to it, "How to use" appeared with normal font, and "Benefits" tab disappeared.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically does what you wrote in your code.

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(
                    new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        //as tab 2 selected it set text to tab 2
                        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                            selected.setText(tab.getText());
                            tab.setCustomView(selected);
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
     //as tab 1 unselected it set NO text to tab 1 in it 
                            unselected.setText(tab.getText());
                            tab.setCustomView(unselected);
```

Why to set CustomView every time when you just need to change the typeface?

I have an Kotlin code  that was converted to JAVA code,  it looks like shit in JAVA, but it works:

```
 private void setTypefaceToTab(Context context, TabLayout tabLayout, TabLayout.Tab tab, int stylem) {
            if (tab != null && context != null) {
                try {
                     View var10000 = ((ViewGroup)tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tab.getPosition());
                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)var10000;
                    var10000 = layout.getChildAt(1);
                    TextView tabTextView = (TextView)var10000;
                    tabTextView.setTextSize (***Text Size***);
                    tabTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-condensed",stylem));
                } catch (Exception var7) {
                    Log.d ("EXC",var7.toString ());
                }
            }
        }
```

Then just use it at tabselectedlistener and in onCreate to set typeface for the first selected tab:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
 setTypefaceToTab(context,tablayout, tablayout.getTabAt (tablayout.getSelectedTabPosition ()),Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
...
}
```

and in tabListener:

```
  private void tabListener(){
            tablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener (new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener () {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                            setTypefaceToTab(context,tablayout,tab,Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    setTypefaceToTab(context,tablayout,tab,Typeface.NORMAL);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    
                }
            });
        }
```

Hope it is what you wanted

Comment: Thanksssss a lot... it's working... I spent more than 6 hrs on this.